# Get value from std::tuple by std::type_identity

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that will get a value out of a tuple by a special type that multiple types can be flag as by inheriting std::type_identity<special_type>.

I want to get the `Things::GetThing()` to be working below.

Using C++20 is fine.

Is this possible?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename...Types>
class Things
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    auto& GetThing() {
        // what to do here?
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Types...> things{};
};

struct FooType {};

struct FooA : std::type_identity<FooType> {};
struct FooB : std::type_identity<FooType> {};
struct Bar {};

int main()
{
    {
        Things<FooA, Bar> things1;
        auto& foo = things1.GetThing<FooType>();
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), FooA&>);
    }
        
    {
        Things<FooB, Bar> things2;
        auto& foo = things2.GetThing<FooType>();
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo), FooB&>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the index first, then use `std::get<index>(tuple)` to get the right element.

One way to obtain the index is using a fold expression over `&&` or `||`. Note the use of an immediately-invoked lambda to turn `index` into a compile-time constant.

```
constexpr std::size_t index = []{
    std::size_t index = 0;
    ((std::is_base_of_v<std::type_identity<T>, Types> || (index++, false)) || ...);
    return index;
}();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well! And I could refactor the need for std::type_identity<T>.